# Асинхронные бесконечные циклы

Tags: c#

недавно начал изучать c#, есть приложение windows forms app, с событиями уже разобрался и при нажатии клавиш делаю нужные действия (запрос на сайт, обновить данные и тд.). Сейчас пробую реализовать асинхронные бесконечные циклы, с помощью Task, await и asyns. Создал следующее:

```
private async Task Go()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await ChangeStatus();
        await SendStatusToServer("1", "1");                
    }
}
```

Функции внутри выглядят примерно вот так:

```
private async Task ChangeStatus()
{
    btn.Text = Status() ? "Выключить" : "Включить";
    await Task.Delay(1000);            
}

private async Task SendStatusToServer(string id, string hash)
{
    string urlStat = "...";
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var pars = new NameValueCollection();
        pars.Add("id", id);
        pars.Add("hash", hash);
        webClient.UploadValues(urlStat, pars);
        await Task.Delay(60000);
    }
}
```

Вот тут и заключается вся проблема, все эти функции выполняются с разной задержкой, на самом деле их будет больше двух, и сейчас цикл не может завершиться, пока не закончится вторая функция, понимаю что двигаюсь куда-то не туда, поэтому прошу помочь.

Comment: `ChangeStatus();` полностью бессмысленный метод. Из вопроса не понятно зачем нужен цикл, да еще и бесконечный?

Comment: Ну сделайте две отдельных асинхронных функции с бесконечными циклами ))  И ожидайте их обе через Task.WhenAll

Comment: @crazyelf Спасибо, не знал про Task.WhenAll, напишите, пожалуйста, ответ ниже, что бы можно было отметить как верный!

Comment: @bulson единственное решение, которое смог придумать, потому что нужно отслеживать запуск сторонней программы, которая никакие запросы мне не отдаёт и может в любой момент закрыться, поэтому в функции Status() я проверяю, запущена ли она, и если что-то с ней случилось - оповестить пользователя.

Comment: Сдается мне, что вы пошли по неверному пути. Грузить свое приложение бесконечной проверкой доступности др.программы неправильно. Ваше приложение должно проверять доступность только в момент, когда это требуется, т.е. перед тем как отправить стороннему приложению данные или же получить от него данные, а не все время как это вы пытаетесь реализовать.

Comment: Пока что додумался только до этого, но, думаю, с опытом, переделаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать две отдельных асинхронных функции, каждую со своим бесконечным циклом. И потом ожидать сразу обе эти задачи с помощью метода [Task.WhenAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2), который ждёт завершения всех задач, переданных ему в качестве аргумента.